# Laptop disconnects from WiFi and is unable to reconnect

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have a Windows 10 laptop, which has the odd feature of disconnecting time to time from the WiFi, and it cannot reconnect to the network, unless I put it into sleep mode and restart it. My phone doesn't have any issues on the same network, and the same laptop doesn't have any problems on other networks either.

Comment: disable the wireless network adapter, then re-enable it.

Comment: @Moab Would you consider telling me, why would that help?

Comment: does the same thing as sleep,

Comment: Go into Device Manager and select the card, Properties. Go to the Power Management tab and disable (uncheck) "Allow the computer to turn this card off... "  See if that helps you.

Comment: @John How comes that I have this problem on this specific network?

Comment: It depends on how frequently you use the keyboard, so I was suggesting this as a possibility. Another thing to try is updating the Wireless driver for the card.

Comment: @John Device Manager claims having the latest driver. Let's try your other idea.